# raster2pgsql error

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I am attempting load ~500 rasters in a PostGIS table. They are .Hdr/.dat files. I am using raster2pgsql. I am able to load the first 260 rasters, but the remaining rasters fail with the following error:

```
Processing 1/198: /media/sf_C_DRIVE/Courses/num_methods/final_project/snodas/masked/snodas_v2_insert/us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012020905HP001.Hdr
ERROR 1: Maximum number of characters allowed reached.
ERROR: convert_raster: Could not open raster: /media/sf_C_DRIVE/Courses/num_methods/final_project/snodas/masked/snodas_v2_insert/us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012020905HP001.Hdr
ERROR: process_rasters: Could not process raster: /media/sf_C_DRIVE/Courses/num_methods/final_project/snodas/masked/snodas_v2_insert/us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2012020905HP001.Hdr
ERROR: Unable to process rasters
```

At first I thought the file name had too many characters, but it is the same lenghth/format as the other files that loaded successfully. I looked at the .Hdr files, but they seem good, and the .dat files are binary - so not sure I can get anything from them.

The data was downloaded from the following website (from the specified ftp)

http://nsidc.org/data/docs/noaa/g02158_snodas_snow_cover_model/

Here is my version of PostGIS:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
                                                                          postgis_full_version                                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="2.1.0 r11822" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

Also, when looking at these files with gdal, I have the same issue:

```
14:22:30 $ gdalinfo us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2004010505HP001.Hdr
Driver: SNODAS/Snow Data Assimilation System
Files: us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2004010505HP001.Hdr
       us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2004010505HP001.dat
Size is 6935, 3351
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-124.733749999998366,52.874583333332339)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333333333,-0.008333333333333)
Metadata:
  Data_Units=Meters / 1000.000000
  Description=Modeled snow water equivalent, total of snow layers
  Start_Date=2004/01/05 06:00:00
  Stop_Date=2004/01/05 06:00:00
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-124.7337500,  52.8745833) (124d44' 1.50"W, 52d52'28.50"N)
Lower Left  (-124.7337500,  24.9495833) (124d44' 1.50"W, 24d56'58.50"N)
Upper Right ( -66.9420833,  52.8745833) ( 66d56'31.50"W, 52d52'28.50"N)
Lower Right ( -66.9420833,  24.9495833) ( 66d56'31.50"W, 24d56'58.50"N)
Center      ( -95.8379167,  38.9120833) ( 95d50'16.50"W, 38d54'43.50"N)
Band 1 Block=6935x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=1518.000 
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Versus

```
14:24:58 $ gdalinfo us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2009021105HP001.Hdr
ERROR 1: Maximum number of characters allowed reached.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'us_ssmv11034tS__T0001TTNATS2009021105HP001.Hdr'.
```

Here is an example of a raster that is not working:

The .dat file:

[dat_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B502B_-zy8HkeDlGb0lySG1adGs/view?usp=sharing)

And the .Hdr file

[Hdr_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B502B_-zy8HkZG9PY08xQUlxQ0k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How big is the raster file.  There is a size limit for postgis raster.  So if it exceeds, you will have to tile them to load with the -t switch. http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader

Comment: Each raster is 45.4 MB. I don't think this is the issue because the other 260 rasters loaded with no problem and are the same exact size

Comment: Which version do you run? I could not find the same messages from the source code of the 2.2 version http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.2/db/dd0/raster2pgsql_8c.html. However I would still make a try by shortening the filenames, they may exceed the length limits of PosgreSQL identifiers. Perhaps raster2pgsql is adding characters to the names while it is doing the processing.

Comment: added the postgis version and the additional info about gdal

Comment: Also, I tried shortening the file names, and the associated metadata in the .Hdr file, but still get the same error....

Comment: How about importing the first 250 and then importing the next 250 in a separate operation. Hdr/Dat sounds like Esri GRID format, if this is the case you've got serious problems with your file names, see http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_the_ESRI_grid_format the section titled Grid data storage

Comment: Okay given you have the same error with GDAL, likely culprit is your GDAL.  Have you tried upgrading GDAL.  Your GDAL version is pretty old. GDAL 1.11.1 came and GDAL 2.0.0 came recently. Also your PostgSI version is very old too. You shuld be running at least 2.1.3 (we are at 2.1.7)

Comment: OK, So I updated GDAL to 1.9.2 and still get the same error with the gdalinfo command. Michael, let me clarify, I can load about 250 or the raster, but the remaining I cannot open with gdal, qgis, or postgis -even one at a time. I don't think it is the character issue, because I can get read about 250 rasters with the same exact naming conversion and grid. I am starting to think these are "bad" rasters - not sure what that means though...

Comment: Could you put one failing raster somewhere for easy download? It looks like the license allows it. Put the license text into same place if you want to feel safe.

Comment: sure, just added the Hdr and dat file

Comment: OK, just figured it out, on line 4 or 5 it has "Created by module comment: number BARD codes:" followed by a series of numbers. It looks like this series a numbers was too long. After I shorten this string I am able to read the raster with gdal! Any ideas on how to do a batch script to shorten this line for all these rasters?

Comment: Its not super clear from the question but I'm just noting this is still an issue with SNODAS data and the above comment from @Rowan_Gaffney solves the issue.